# How to use High Resolution Kinect Image with openni_launch

Tags: kinect, openni, openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to switch from using the launch file in openni_camera to using the launch file in openni_launch, because I have moved all of my perception algorithms to be in nodelets, and want the savings that nodelets provide. However, I require that I have the RGB camera of the kinect at SXGA and I am having difficulties figuring out how to do this.

If I change the resolution of the camera using dynamic_reconfigure's reconfigure_gui, it will will no longer publish the depth_registered point cloud, and gives me the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1324055818.746734909]: Depth resolution (640x480) does not match RGB resolution (1280x1024)
```

My second question is also, why does this new method require having a calibration file? How can I use whatever calibration that was used in the openni_camera launch file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12372/how-to-use-high-resolution-kinect-image-with-openni_launch/) by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) on ROS Answers with karma: 765 on 2011-12-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay, while this doesn't exactly answer my question, I've found that there is a nodelet that works in the same way as the node that is launched in the openni_camera launch file. I've written a launch file to use that nodelet instead and I've got it working the way I'd like it to.

---

Originally posted by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) with karma: 765 on 2011-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0